# Floating Point UniqueValueRenderer

Tags: arcobjects, raster

I am trying to build a unique value renderer using ArcObjects .NET.  All the samples that I have seen use the attribute table to build the UniqueValueRenderer.  However, my raster does not have an attribute table and when I try to build the attribute table I get the following exception "Can't build VAT for multiband or floating-point raster dataset".

Currently my renderer is defaulting to stretched.  When I look at it in ArcMap - Properties - Symbology it is set to stretched (this is what we default rasters to in our code if there is not an attribute table).

In ArcMap, I can click on Unique Values under Properties - Symbology.  A message box pops up stating "Unique values do not exist.  Do you want to compute unique values?"  If I click yes, then  my unique floating point values are there.

How can I programmatically define these unique values and set this is as the default symbology / renderer for my floating point raster?

Comment: There's a good reason for this limitation: floating point grids potentially have as many unique values as they have cells. Attempting to assign a unique graphical symbol to each cell could quickly overwhelm the machine. If this is related to [your previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66897/esri-raster-remap-with-decimals), why don't you solve both problems simultaneously simply by not dividing the values by 100? Your reclassified grid will be integral, it will have a VAT, and is easily rendered.

Comment: That makes sense, but I would think there is a way to do it since you can select unique values in ArcMap.  My concern with not dividing by 100 is that when I combine that raster with another raster with values < 10 the output raster will be off.